# How to connect a node server without browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, tcp, websocket

I am using node-jet library as message broker using a websocket.

In my code, there is a deamon and there are peers connect to it. In libary documentation its says peers can connect either by websocket or trivial tcp connection (never used second one before)

Here is server code I try to connect (its running when I try to connect)

https://github.com/lipp/node-jet/blob/master/examples/todo/todo-server.js

Everything works fine if I run my peer javascript inside a browser however, I am not able to run it from console.

```
 var peer3 = new jet.Peer({
 url: 'wss://217.78.109.178:8090'
//url: (window.location.protocol === 'http:' ? 'ws://' : 'wss://') + 
window.location.host
})
```

documentation says it will use trivial tcp if no url provided so I also tried this. Again works in browser but not standalone. Any idea ? how can I solve this problem ?

```
var peer3 = new jet.Peer({
})

$ node Peer.js
Peer: connect failed { no remote stack
    name: 'jet.ConnectionClosed',
    message: '',
    url: 'https://github.com/lipp/node-
    jet/blob/master/doc/peer.markdown#jetconnectionclosed'
}
```

Comment: `$ node Peer.js` is used to run it standalone for any nodejs code on the server. Try the same with original code and print something on output.

Comment: I already tried that before. So you achieved it with node-jet library ?